# Are "required" HTML fields not enforced on Django Admin intermediate pages?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I have the following abbreviated HTML for an intermediate Django admin page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends base_url %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
    ...
    <select name="my_name" id="my_id" required>
        <option disabled selected> --- </option> <br />
    ...
    </select>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_action" />
    <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Update" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

However, my `required` attribute does not seem to work, and clicking "Update" submits the form even if no selection has been made.

Am I missing something special about how Django builds intermediate pages?

Happy to provide more code if needed, just removed most of it and replaced with `...` for brevity's sake.

*Edit: I was able to sidestep the issue by raising an error message if my field wasn't filled out, but that seems messier since it kicks the user back to the Admin page each time:*

```py
is_valid_form = 'my_id' in request.POST

if not is_valid_form:
    fail_message = (
        "Error: All fields are required.")
        admin_page.message_user(
            request, fail_message, messages.ERROR)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())
```

Comment: A select is just a normal html element. It works the same whether you use django or write the html by hand.  `required` should be handled by the browser. But for a select, it only has an effect if the default option has `value=""` (empty string). I don't understand why you have `...` instead of options inside your select.

Comment: Aha, thank you so much! that was actually my issue! I didn't have `value=""` on the options for my select fields.

I just included `...` in the description to shorten the code that was displayed. I have options on my actual code. I've edited the description to reflect this. If you want to make this an Answer I'll mark it accepted.